# JPA not a known entity type

Tags: java, jpa

i have the following entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_SPJ_PEOPLE")
public class People implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Column(name="PEOPLE_ID", unique=true)
private int personID = 0;

@Column(name="PEOPLE_NAME")
private String name = "";

@Column(name="PEOPLE_PROFILEPATH")
 private String profilePath = "";

@Column(name="PEOPLE_PERSON_TYPE")
private String personType = "";

@Column(name="PEOPLE_DEPARTMENT")
private String department = "";

@Column(name="PEOPLE_JOB")
private String job = "";

@Column(name="PEOPLE_ORDER")
private int order = 0;

@Column(name="PEOPLE_ADULT")
private boolean adult = false;

@Column(name="PEOPLE_AKA")
private String alsoKnownAs = "";

@Lob
@Column(name="PEOPLE_BIOGRAPHY")
private String biography = "";

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="PEOPLE_BIRTHDAY")
private Date birthday = null;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="PEOPLE_DEADTHDAY")
private Date deathday = null;

@Column(name="PEOPLE_HOMEPAGE")
private String homepage = "";

@Column(name="PEOPLE_BIRTHPLACE")
private String birthPlace = "";

@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="TBL_SPJ_PEOPLE_CAST", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PEOPLE_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="CAST_PEOPLE_ID")})
private List<CastPeople> casts = null;

@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="TBL_SPJ_PEOPLE_CREW", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PEOPLE_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="CREW_PEOPLE_ID")})
private List<CrewPeople> crews = null;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="PEOPLE_ID", referencedColumnName="PEOPLE_ID")
private List<Image> images = null;

public People() {}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transient
public List<String> getPeople() {
    List<String> people = new ArrayList<String>();

    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("SPJUnit");
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT p.name FROM People p");

    people = query.getResultList();

    return people;
}

public int getPersonID() {
    return personID;
}
public void setPersonID(int personID) {
    this.personID = personID;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getProfilePath() {
    return profilePath;
}
public void setProfilePath(String profilePath) {
    this.profilePath = profilePath;
}
public String getPersonType() {
    return personType;
}
public void setPersonType(String personType) {
    this.personType = personType;
}
public String getDepartment() {
    return department;
}
public void setDepartment(String department) {
    this.department = department;
}
public String getJob() {
    return job;
}
public void setJob(String job) {
    this.job = job;
}
public int getOrder() {
    return order;
}
public void setOrder(int order) {
    this.order = order;
}
public boolean isAdult() {
    return adult;
}
public void setAdult(boolean adult) {
    this.adult = adult;
}
public String getAlsoKnownAs() {
    return alsoKnownAs;
}
public void setAlsoKnownAs(String alsoKnownAs) {
    this.alsoKnownAs = alsoKnownAs;
}
public String getBiography() {
    return biography;
}
public void setBiography(String biography) {
    this.biography = biography;
}
public Date getBirthday() {
    return birthday;
}
public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
    this.birthday = birthday;
}
public Date getDeathday() {
    return deathday;
}
public void setDeathday(Date deathday) {
    this.deathday = deathday;
}
public String getHomepage() {
    return homepage;
}
public void setHomepage(String homepage) {
    this.homepage = homepage;
}
public String getBirthPlace() {
    return birthPlace;
}
public void setBirthPlace(String birthPlace) {
    this.birthPlace = birthPlace;
}
public List<CastPeople> getCasts() {
    return casts;
}
public void setCasts(List<CastPeople> casts) {
    this.casts = casts;
}
public List<CrewPeople> getCrews() {
    return crews;
}
public void setCrews(List<CrewPeople> crews) {
    this.crews = crews;
}
public List<Image> getImages() {
    return images;
}
public void setImages(List<Image> images) {
    this.images = images;
}
}
```

And this persistance.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
version="1.0">

<persistence-unit name="SPJUnit" transaction-type="JTA">

    <jta-data-source>jdbc/peoplesDB</jta-data-source>

    <class>de.hof.university.spj.beans.People</class>

</persistence-unit>
```

I use the entitymanager here:

```
public void buildDatabase() throws IOException, SAXException {
    logger.info("Set up Database.");

    if(factory == null) {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("SPJUnit");
    }

    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT p.title FROM Person p");

    boolean importData = (query.getResultList().size() == 0);

    if(importData) {
        this.importData(em);
    } else {
        logger.info("Data already imported.");
    }

    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
}

    private void importData(EntityManager em) throws SAXException, IOException {
    logger.info("Import Data into Database.");

    XMLParser myParser = new XMLParser();

    List<People> allPeoples = myParser.parsePeople("people.xml", new XMLPeopleHandler());       

    for(People people: allPeoples) {
        logger.info("Persist Person: " + people.getName());
        em.persist(people);
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: People is not a known entity type
```

if i dont use jta in my persistence.xml and set this instead:

```
<properties>
        <property name="persistence-context.persist-on-commit" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:./data/datastore" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="admin" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="admin" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
```

Everything works fine... so it has to be a problem with jta?

Comment: Sounds like it's more how Hibernate integrates with JTA.  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936921/spring-hibernate-jta-hibernatetransactionmanager-or-jtatransactionmanager

Comment: the tables arent created after i created the entitymanager. without jta the tables are created. why arent the tables automatically created when i use a jta-datasource? makes no sense to me.